# How to change font size for overflowed tabs drop down list of Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

[image: Image for your reference]

How can I change the font size of this overflowed tabs drop down list present in eclipse ide.
List is marked in the image.

I want to change the font size of this drop-down list.
I tried using PartImpl and stackRenderer files, but not able to find any approach.

Comment: Looks like that list is shown by `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt.BasicPartList` which doesn't seem to have a simple way to change the font. For an RCP you could perhaps use a custom `StackRenderer` extending the standard one and override `showAvailableItems`

Comment: @greg-449 i tried overriding showAvailableItems but from there I am still not able to access the font size. How can i do that ?

Comment: You use CSS classes and ids to specify the font of controls. You can use something like `StyledCellLabelProvider` in a table to deal with bold etc.

Comment: @greg-449 what to do with StyledCellLabelProvider?? i have tried with css as well but I am not able to figure out which table it is and what changes should i make

Comment: You are going to have to write a replacement for BasicPartList and use all that stuff in the replacement

Comment: @greg-449 which funtion of BasicPartList should i override to change the font size

Comment: No idea, study the source.

Comment: @greg-449 none of the functions of basicPartList is helping with the font size